# Associating a temporary (non-DB) model to a simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a simple_form, that doesn't really apply to a normal model. If I have the object just set to `:thing` it seems to work.

However, I want it to have some validation. In other questions, I've found that this means that I NEED to have a model... I'm not sure what needs to be in that model, however. So, I made I model, but I can't figure out how to hook them up.

```
class ClientEmail
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  validate :cannot_be_present

  attr_accessor :to_domain

  def cannot_be_present
    newDomClients = Client.where("email like :foo", {:foo => "%#{to_domain}%"})
    errors.add(:base, "There cannot be any emails already in the database with the target domain" ) if newDomClients.length > 0
    end
end
```

and the simple_form is:

```
= simple_form_for(@client_email, url: { action: "update" }, html: {class: "search_form",  method: :put }) do |f|
  .input-row
    = f.input :newDomain, :label => "New domain name", :required => true
```

(etc)

Initially, it said that @client_email was nil, so I initialized it (which seems unlikely to be necessary given Rails...) with:

```
- @client_email = ClientEmail.new
```

but that tells me that ClientEmail doesn't have a to_key method, so I'm clearly missing a bunch of infrastructure somewhere.

Comment: You want to pass some data to params hash that doesn't belongs to any model and validate it right?

Comment: You'll also need `extend ActiveModel::Naming`. More on the docs api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Naming.html

Comment: @MehmetAdilİstikbal Basically, yeah. But in a different question here, I was told that the best way to do that was to make a model...

Comment: You have created a model `ClientEmail` in order for a `Client` (which model probably exists already) to fill their email ? So basically the client is not your app user (because in this case the client has to submit an email and a password to be able to log to your website..). But rather has been created by a member of the company (back office) and this member of the company has to fill the email of the client later ?

Comment: In this case, it's a page for an admin (back office user) to change the email of a bunch of clients, yeah...

Comment: I am not an expert but to me, a model = a table in the database. If your client model is designed such has it has no email field then ok, create a child of `client` named `clientemail`. Otherwise just edit your client record through edit action of `client` controller. If you're afraid your backofficers mess up with other fields than email, then create a specific action in the client controller just for changing/adding email. If you stick to second method with additional email, please tell all your fields in that model that need be added. Also what is to_domain, what is new_domain.

Comment: The problem is that this button will act on MANY clients at once. So this doesn't belong in the client model, to me... So I created a new controller with no model, originally... but in order to get the error reporting I need a model, I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a form with an object that belongs to a model you can't create fields that doesn't belongs to that model. You need to create form like this in order to do that:

`= simple_form_for(:client_email, url......)`

if you create form with symbol like this you can create any field in this form and send to controller that you want. params hash won't change too much and you can call your special fields like this:

`params[:client_email][:your_field_name]`

since this field doesn't belongs to a model its better to validate it in controller.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That defeats the purpose. I want to use the simple_form f.error capability.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I needed:

```
  include Virtus.model
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
```

I'm not sure exactly what Virtus is. it's probably possible without it, but it's a library I already have...